# Can i remove sail from laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-sail

Recently i was assigned a task to upgrade old laravel project, there is one controller and not more than 20 files in need to migrate with 200 lines of code on them(on average).

Just for this i setup laravel latest 8.1 , but it comes with a lot of garbage, including sails. i just needed laravel-5.4 like (supporting php-8) with mysql (no sails, mail and other things).

Can i remove sails from it, i couldn't find good documentation on the first page of google to use a minimal laravel so i came here.

I didn't mean to offend anyone but laravel is getting fraustrating with lots of bad bad abstraction i think.

Comment: you cannot do manually from laravel 5.4 to latest use https://laravelshift.com/   and those are not garbage `sails, mail and other things` these are key feature in latest laravel

Comment: @KamleshPaul You can absolutely migrate manually. Shift just makes it easier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can remove it like any other **packagist** package using **composer**

```
composer remove vendor/package
```

Comment: Also, you need to remove the `docker-compose.yml` manually.